# Clean way to separate functions/subroutine declaration from definition in Fortran 90

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am working on a big Fortran 90 code, with a lot of modules. What bothers me is that when I modify the inner code of a function inside a module (without changing its mask), my Makefile (whose dependencies are based on "use") recompile every file that "use" that modified module, and recursively.

But when modifying the inner code of a function without touching its input/output, recompiling other files than the modified one is useless, no?

So I would like to separate the function declaration from their definition, like with the .h files in C or C++. What is the clean way to do this? Do I have to use Fortran include/preprocessor `#include`, or is there a "module/use" way of doing this?

I have tried something like this, but it seems to be quite nonsense...

main.f90

```
program prog

  use foomod_header

  integer :: i

  bar=0
  i=42
  call foosub(i)

end program prog
```

foomod_header.f90

```
module foomod_header

  integer :: bar

  interface 
    subroutine foosub(i)
      integer :: i
    end subroutine
  end interface

end module foomod_header
```

foomod.f90

```
module foomod

  use foomod_header

  contains

  subroutine foosub(i)
    integer ::i

    print *,i+bar

  end subroutine foosub

end module foomod
```

Comment: That way madness lies.  If your compiler already implements the 2008 standard introduction of `submodule`s you can achieve most of what you want by using them.  If it doesn't, use your favourite search engine on the term *fortran compilation cascade* and learn about all the ingenious ways people have derived for getting round this feature of the way all (I think) Fortran compilers have implemented modules.

Comment: Thanks for the magic word "fortran compilation cascade"! But am I missing something: what is suggested [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/268820) is the same as what I tried. But it does not work: foomod.f90 does not compile, saying (ifort): _The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit.   [FOOSUB]_

Comment: The response on the Intel forum that you linked to has errors.   You cannot manually (using an INTERFACE block) provide an interface to a module procedure (the special separate interface bodies for separate module subprograms, which are used in submodules, aside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If submodules aren't an option (and they are ideal for this), then what you can do is make the procedure an external procedure and provide an interface for that procedure in a module.  For example:

```
! Program.f90
PROGRAM p
  USE Interfaces
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ...
  CALL SomeProcedure(xyz)
END PROGRAM p

! Interfaces.f90
MODULE Interfaces
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE SomeProcedure(some_arg)
      USE SomeOtherModule
      IMPLICIT NONE
      TYPE(SomeType) :: some_arg
    END SUBROUTINE SomeProcedure
  END INTERFACE
END MODULE Interfaces

! SomeProcedure.f90
SUBROUTINE SomeProcedure(some_arg)
  USE SomeOtherModule
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE(SomeType) :: some_arg
  ...
END SUBROUTINE SomeProcedure
```

Some important notes:

- There must only ever be one interface definition for a procedure accessible in a scope.  Inside a subprogram the interface for the procedure defined by the subprogram is also considered defined - hence inside the subprogram you must not permit an interface block for procedures defined by the subprogram to be accessible.  In terms of the example, this means that you must not have a `USE Interfaces` statement without an only clause inside the `SomeProcedure` external procedure.
- If you do change the arguments or similar of the procedure inside SomeProcedure.f90 you had better make sure that you change the corresponding interface block inside the module!
- If you can use F2003, the IMPORT statement can make life easier.  Otherwise you might have to have additional modules (such as `SomeOtherModule` in the example) to share type definitions and the like between the Interfaces module and the external procedure.
- If you have private entities or components relevant to the procedure then Fortran's rules entity and component accessibility may prevent you using this approach.
- Typically some sort of whole program analysis is done at high levels of optimization.  That analysis is typically much slower than the actual parsing of the code - splitting out procedures in this manner may not actually shorten build times significantly under these conditions.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, very useful to me because at this time I must stick to F90. What I fear with this option: I think there are different subroutines having the same name in different modules. So making them external procedures will cause me trouble at the link, no?

Comment: Restricting yourself to Fortran 90 in 2015 is a little bizarre - Fortran 95 plus TR 15581 "allocatable" support is pretty much a given in all actively maintained compilers.  Yes - the names of external procedures are global identifiers, and must be unique.

Comment: I totally aggree, but I am working with old guys that seem to be emotionnaly attached to their prehistoric tools and don't like change:) If it was up to me, I would rewrite the whole code in c++!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the cleanest solution is to change the build system.

The real dependency introduced by a `USE` statement is not the source-code file, but the generated `.mod` file, which acts as a sort of "binary header file". I.e. where makefiles typically contain something like

```
MyProgram.o: MyModule.f90
```

what they really should contain is

```
MyProgram.o: MyModule.mod
MyModule.mod: MyModule.f90
```

with the creation of the `.mod` file being done in a way, that ensures an unchanged file-system timestamp, if the interface hasn't actually changed.

Sadly, compiler-support is awkward. Most compilers will overwrite the `.mod` file anyway, so the build process must at the same time detect, that the `.mod` file hasn't changed, e.g. by restoring the old modification time if the contents are unchanged, but at the same time needs to avoid recompiling the source file unnecessarily, which requires updating the modification time of the `.mod` file.

Additionally, some compilers (Intel, *cough*) add a binary time-stamp to the *contents* of the `.mod` files, that needs to be manually excluded from the comparison and has changed binary position across releases. This adds effort when supporting multiple compilers.

Comment: *Maybe the cleanest solution is to change the build system.*  That may have been a defensible argument when the question was asked, but now that all the Fortran compilers in widespread use have implemented submodules, I don't think it is.